# making ruby 1.9 default on os x

Tags: ruby, macos, operating-system

How do I make ruby 1.9 the default version to use instead of the 1.8.x that is by default installed on os x?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As of v2.1.3, the "correct" [**MacPorts**](http://www.macports.org/) way of setting a specific version of a package as the default is to use the `select` command, like this:

`sudo port select --set ruby ruby19`

There doesn't appear to be any documentation about this command in [the MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/#using). You can however run `port help select` to get a very limited description. This functionality replaces the `+nosuffix` "variant" style of setting the default version.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend installing the RVM tool from  http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/  (it has instructions on [installing it](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

It allows you to have multiple versions of ruby and gems. After installing RVM, then install the Ruby 1.9 you want, using:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.1
```

To make it the default one:

```
rvm --default ruby-1.9.1
```

After this, it will be the default ruby.

Comment: I would avoid being too specific by not including the patch level
ie: 
     rvm --default 1.9.1

Answer (score 3):

RVM is great for setting up multiple environments with different versions of Ruby and gems.

If you however just want to have Ruby 1.9 you can simply install it using MacPort. It will take precedence over the one already installed by default on OS X.

1. Download [MacPort](http://www.macports.org/) if you haven't already. It's the Mac package manager.
2. On a Terminal, use MacPort to install Ruby 1.9 and RubyGems
   `sudo port selfupdate

   sudo port install ruby19

   sudo port install rb-rubygems`

You should then have Ruby 1.9 installed and ahead on the path. Do a ruby -v to check. Use Ruby gems to install any other Ruby components like Rails.

Ports are installed in the /opt/local/bin directory and MacPort updates the PATH environment variable so that these are picked up before the /usr/bin pre-installed packages.

Comment: Yes, that is a good answer too. The only comment I would make, is that with RVM you can get different gem sets. Different gemsets are required if you are trying to do both Rails 2.x and Rails 3.0 work. Plus, I've had problems where one version of Ruby would break certain apps (because of bugs in the ruby interpreter).

Comment: There is another problem with this approach. Ruby1.9 (installed using macports)  is called "ruby1.9". So if you issue "ruby" in terminal you will still get ruby 1.8.7 installed on the system (since usr/local/bin is in the path). You could set a symbolic link to ruby1.9 in usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 3):

you could create an alias rather than a symlink...this way both versions are left intact.  add the following line to .profile in user's home folder (create if doesn't exist):

```
alias ruby='/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9'
```

then source the file:

```
source .profile
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say skip the rvm.

In my case, MacPorts did prepend /opt/local/bin to my path, but installed ruby 1.9 as ruby1.9.  (Leaving ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby.)

By far the easiest way to fix:

```
sudo su
cd /opt/local/bin
ln -s ruby1.9 ruby
```

Poof.  Done.

Exact commands:

```
nsmcs-macbook-pro:~ nsmc$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
nsmcs-macbook-pro:~ nsmc$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
nsmcs-macbook-pro:~ nsmc$ which ruby1.9
/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9
nsmcs-macbook-pro:~ nsmc$ sudo su
Password:
sh-3.2# cd /opt/local/bin/
sh-3.2# ls -l ruby*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  admin  9040 Feb 16 07:43 ruby1.9
sh-3.2# ln -s ruby1.9 ruby
sh-3.2# which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
sh-3.2# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10]
```

Comment: I had to pull the same symbolic link trick with MacPort's gem1.9 to trick gem into using the non-framework version of Ruby.